# In Spanish, how do I express the concept of "self" and "being" from a philosophical and psychological perspective?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, español-neutral, psicología

I am not looking for the verb "to be". At least not as an entire answer. I want to understand how Spanish speakers talk about their "self" and who they are. I want to know words that accentuate conversations about "self" and "being" in the Spanish language. In English I learned, "Me, myself, and I". There is the famous quote, "To be, or not to be". These are powerful concepts that I find elusive in the Spanish language. Also, I learned from psychology the concepts of Id, ego, and superego, as well as conscious, subconscious, and super-conscious.

How do Spanish speakers discuss the concepts of "self" and "being" from a philosophical and psychological perspective?

How do Spanish speakers discuss WHO they are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the personal pronoun *yo* as a noun in philosophical contexts. Check out its definition in the DLE:

> **[yo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=cCEHAgu)**
>
> 1. pron. person. 1.ª pers. m. y f. sing. Forma que, en nominativo, designa a la persona que habla o escribe. *Yo estoy muy tranquila.*
> 2. m. Fil. Sujeto humano en cuanto persona. *El yo. Mi yo.*
> 3. m. Psicol. Parte consciente del individuo, mediante la cual cada persona se hace cargo de su propia identidad y de sus relaciones con el medio.

The second and third entries state that the word is used as a noun (*el yo*, *mi yo*). See the following examples:

> *Existe una "despolitización" radical, antropológica, por el hecho de que "el yo" como conciencia total está dejando de ser el centro de imputación de las actitudes políticas.*
>
> *Porque por no perderlo ya que sacrifiqué lo que para mí valía más, mi yo, mi alma, mi existencia, quizá hasta el cariño tuyo...*

You can also use the verb *ser* as a noun:

> **[ser<sup>2</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Xe5NPsQ)**
>
> 1. m. Esencia o naturaleza.

Example:

> *Pero, aparte de este realismo trascendente, defendían otros un realismo inmanente: los universales existían como tales universales en la naturaleza de las cosas; más aún, las cosas son tanto más reales cuanto más universales; de modo que el universal máximo, que es el ser, es el fundamento y raíz de toda realidad.*

And finally the Freudian concepts of "id, ego and superego" are expressed in Spanish as "el [ello](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ESsilCu), el yo y el [superyó](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YlNnmQB)". Check [this Spanish Wikipedia entry](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ello,_yo_y_supery%C3%B3). You can also use the words *[ego](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EQoDoir)* and *[superego](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YjG8NNn)* in Spanish.